# Getting 'unexpected EOF' in gorilla websockets

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have the following read pump for a gorilla websockets connection in Go.

```
func (c *connection) readPump() {

//function to close the websocket
defer func() {
    socketsHub.unregister <- c
    c.ws.Close()
}()

c.ws.SetReadLimit(maxMessageSize)
c.ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
c.ws.SetPongHandler(func(string) error {
    c.ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
    return nil
})

for {

    //create a new socketMessage
    message := socketMessage{}

    //get the json message from the socket
    err := c.ws.ReadJSON(message)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        break
    }
    //add the connection to the message
    message.Connection = c

    shouldBroadcast := message.Process()

    //if the new message should be broadcasted to any user (includeing the
    //one who sent it)
    if shouldBroadcast {
        socketsHub.broadcast <- message
    }
}
```

}

This is the code we are using on the frontend:

```
if (window["WebSocket"]) {
  conn = new WebSocket("wss://localhost/api/ws")

  conn.onclose = function(evt) {
    console.log($("<div><b>Connection closed.</b></div>"))
  }
} else {
  console.log($("<div><b>Your browser does not support WebSockets.</b></div>"))
}
```

Everytime I load any page I get an `'websocket: close 1005'` error. I am about to go crazy. Any help would be great.

Comment: Seems like you can connect but then get disconnected. Probably by the server. Can you uncomment your defer function to close the websocket and see what happens? More code would probably also help to find the error. Do you have errors getting logged from the ReadJSON method?

Comment: Just wonder, how long is your `pongWait`?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you have shown.  Error 1005 indicates that the client closed the connection. I suggest showing more of the client code and the code you use to write to the websocket.